# How to create new Angular 2 App

Tags: angular

I want to create a new angular 2 project.

Using the Angular command line interface, I only create the latest version of Angular project.

Please help me how to create angular 2 app.

Comment: Is there a reason you would create a new app with Angular v2 and not the most recent version of Angular (v6)?

Comment: Yes, I want to create angular 2 application. Some of the modules in angular 6 are different from angular2

Comment: I think you may have a very difficult time with that ... you are much better off building an Angular v6 app. Some of the modules (like Http) are slightly different ... but in general Angular is Angular. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To create a new Angular2 app using Angular CLI, use the following command:

```
ng new project-name
```

Answer (score -1):

use earlier versions of Angular-Cli . for example this version :

> v1.0.0

u can find it here : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v1.0.0

and to install it via npm , use :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to run this statement on your CMD

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new Project_Name
cd Project_Name
ng serve
```